# Using attribute selector works to add max-width 100% to video but class selector does not

Tags: html, css

My page displays a video tag that should have the CSS style `max-width: 100%`. Using the attribute selector the style gets applied, but using a class selector it does not work.

**This works**

```css
video {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<video>
  <source src="<path-to-video>" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**Does not work**

```css
.my-video-class {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<video class="my-video-class">
  <source src="<path-to-video>" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? Other styles do seem to be respected, e.g. if I add `border-radius: 10px;` that is respected with either approach.

Comment: On what browser this issue shows? Are there any other styles that apply to `video` (hierarchy issue)? Are you able to reproduce this issue using SO snippet? If so, can you prepare said snippet and update your question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

You just need to add `width:100%` to the `.my-video-class`, as it will take the full width available.

Comment: That is not the point of this question. This is not a question about "what will work" but "why this does not work"